# Need to be able to pass danish decimal to MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, knockout.js

In my MVC app, I made this simple test function...

```
Function test(d As Decimal) As JsonResult
  Return Json(d)
End Function
```

Sending .../?d=1900 works fine.

Sending .../?d=1,900 fails with "d" being null.

Sending .../?d=1.900 converts d to 1.9D     <--- I NEED THIS ONE

Since I'm danish, I want to be able to pass 1.900 to "d" so it will be one-thousand-nine-hundred.

I tried setting this in web.config...

...that din't help.

Any idea?

Comment: The query string is not necessarily intended to be human-readable; is it *really* important that it follow a Danish locale? (I.e., *must* it contain a `.`? What's wrong with simply `1900`?) I'm sure this is possible anyway (but I don't know the solution because I don't do web/ASP work), just curious I suppose.

Comment: You mention that `.../?d=1,900 fails with "d" being null`, but how can possibly a value type such as Decimal be null?????? That contradicts with the very base definition of what a value type means in .NET.

Comment: Either convert `1.900` to `1900` on the client, or change the parameter to a string and convert to a decimal inside the controller method.

Comment: It's a query string, so the initial value is a string, which can be null.

Comment: I use knockout to pass json to my MVC controller, so if user enters 1.900 then knockout will send this to my controller and my controller will refuse that value - the controller wants it to be 1900. So Either I tell knockoutjs somehow to be danish culture, or I manually parse values before sending it to controller - or as I would prefer be able to tell MVC to expect danish (1.900) decimals.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin this means I will have to parse a lotta values before sending it to my MVC and I would prefer not to.

Comment: @MojoDK If 1.900 in "danish decimals" is actually nineteen hundred, how do you indicate 1900.54 (nineteen hundred point fifty four) in "danish decimals"?

Comment: Can you URL encode the 1,900?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov if you pass d=1,900 then MVC throws an exception. I don't want to pass null to a decimal, MVC sees 1,900 as a null.

Comment: @MojoDK, you seem to be a little confused about value types and null values and what MVC *sees*. ASP.NET MVC uses CultureInfo.InvariantCulture in order to parse query string parameters. So if you want to be using some custom culture such as Danish or whatever you will have to write a custom model binder and replace the default one to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to be doing here is doing a culture-specific conversion to decimal. If you don't specify a culture, ASP.NET MVC will use the Invariant Culture. Similarly, if you use the decimal.Parse function without a culture will use the system's current culture.

What you need to do is use the function Decimal.Parse with a culture that you supply. [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91fwbcsb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You could set each user's culture up in whatever user/session sort of setup you have, or you could pass it in as a parameter. E.g:

/?d=1,900&culture=da-DK

Then you might pass

```
decimal.Parse(d, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture))
```

Comment: That's a wrong answer. ASP.NET MVC **ALWAYS** uses InvariantCulture when parsing query string parameters. It doesn't assume anything and it doesn't use any system culture. It uses the system culture when parsing values from the POST body payload. The following blog post will provide you with further details about this design decision http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/11/21/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization.aspx

Comment: Which is precisely why I am recommending that he parse the parameters himself if he absolutely must pass in parameters in a danish number format.

Comment: Then please fix the first paragraph of your answer as it is **absolutely wrong**: `If you don't specify a culture, the system will use the system's current culture, which is probably going to be an English form.`. The correct answer is that ASP.NET MVC will **always** use InvariantCulture when parsing query string parameters.

Comment: Do you have a source for your claim so that I may verify / include it? The default behaviour of parsing a decimal using the .Net parse functions when no culture is specified is to use CurrentCulture, which is what I had assumed was happening in this case.

Comment: Sure, please read the blog post linked in my first comment. Or if you don't trust blog posts, like me, simply read the source code of ASP.NET MVC, it's what I do. That's the most reliable source of information.

Comment: @Big Luke ... the "d" here is just a sample. In my real app, I use an Linq-to-sql table as parameter, so I don't have possibility to parse the value since it already been assigned by the controller-parameter.